# FFMPEG mp4 copied to matroska loses last frame

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am running this simple ffmpeg command to change an mp4 video to matroska format so it can support streaming. `ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -c copy out.mkv`. My issue is that the out.mkv file has one less frame than the original mp4 file. It seems to be missing the last frame.

I thought using copy as the codec should retain the same video. Am I missing passing an option to FFmpeg? Thanks.

EDIT: Full Log

```
ffmpeg version 4.2.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.3 (clang-1103.0.32.59)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.2.3_1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags=-fno-stack-check --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack
  libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
  libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
  libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
  libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
  libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
  libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
  libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
    encoder         : Lavf53.24.2
  Duration: 00:00:29.57, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1421 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1032 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 383 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
File 'out.mkv' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, matroska, to 'out.mkv':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 1032 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 12800 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([255][0][0][0] / 0x00FF), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 383 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame=  739 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    5129kB time=00:00:29.54 bitrate=1422.0kbits/s speed= 493x
video:3727kB audio:1386kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.309803%
```

Comment: Share full log.

Comment: See if `-ignore_editlist 1` input option (before `-i`) makes a difference.

Comment: @llogan That didn't help. Its interesting b/c I used an online tool and that one worked fine.

Comment: Does `ffmpeg -sseof -4 -i out.mkv -update 1 last.png` show the last frame?

Comment: @Gyan yes, that command appears to output the last frame

Comment: Then it's present in the output.

Comment: I think I tracked this down to an issue with the extraction stream code I am using.